# passing an argument to ARGV[1]

Tags: bash, shell, unix

We have log files that get generated everyday with the name like

> `log.$AUTOSERVE.mmddyyyy`

the log file contains the data like below:

```
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: ABC MACHINE: 111.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: TERMINATED      JOB: XYZ MACHINE: 222.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: 123 MACHINE: 333.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: 456 MACHINE: 444.test.com 
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: ABC123 MACHINE: 555.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: ABC MACHINE: 111.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: TERMINATED      JOB: XYZ MACHINE: 222.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: 123 MACHINE: 333.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: 456 MACHINE: 444.test.com 
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: ABC123 MACHINE: 555.test.com
```

i have a shell script that filters this `log` file for MACHINE and STATUS search string and counts how many jobs have run on each machine, Here is my code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%m%d%Y')
cat /tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.dt \
  | perl -ne '/STATUS:\s+(\w+).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/ && print join( "\t", $1, $2 ). "\n"' \
  | grep -E '(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)' \
  | cut -f2 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", '$ARGV[1]', $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"' $date_YYYYMMDD \
  > /tmp/output.txt
```

the output i am getting is :

```
ARRAY(0x5569464a3630)   NP2     111.test.com      2
ARRAY(0x5569464a3678)   NP2     222.test.com      2
ARRAY(0x5569464a3648)   NP2     444.test.com      2
ARRAY(0x5569464a3630)   NP2     555.test.com      2
```

i tried changing the `$date_YYYYMMDD` to `$dt:`

```
cat /tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.dt \
  | perl -ne '/STATUS:\s+(\w+).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/ && print join( "\t", $1, $2 ). "\n"' \
  | grep -E '(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)' \
  | cut -f2 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", '$ARGV[1]', $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"' $dt \
  > /tmp/output.txt
```

But i am getting the below error:

```
Can't open 11152023: No such file or directory.
```

what output i am expecting is:

```
11152023   NP2     111.test.com      2
11152023   NP2     222.test.com      2
11152023   NP2     444.test.com      2
11152023   NP2     555.test.com      2
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: Use quotes when your want to be certain of how many argv elements something expands into. `foo "$arg"`, not `foo $arg`.

Comment: Consider running your code through https://shellcheck.net, which catches that and other issues.

Comment: BTW, Stack Overflow supports block quotes -- you don't need to code-format lines individually.

Comment: ...although I wonder if maybe you followed advice from a linter too closely: You have single quotes around `$ARGV[1]` in your perl code, but that's making `$ARGV` be expanded **by the shell**, not by perl, because they end the single-quoted context you have the rest of your perl code in. Don't do that: you probably want `print join("\t", $ARGV[1], $ENV{AUTOSERV}` without any single-quotes.

Comment: (it's also generally suboptimal to jump back and forth between perl and shell this way; you can generally do _all_ the logic just in perl instead of needing to pipe back and forth; the same is also typically true of awk).